# Websphere shutdown not releasing database locks

Tags: java, oracle, websphere, locking

Sometimes when shutting down Websphere there are database locks not released. As a result, when WAS is restarted nobody can work because of these locks, that must be removed manually by the DBA.

It's a Java web application, transactions are XA and the database is Oracle. All the transactional code has a try catch finally and the transaction commit/rollback is done in the finally. I suspect that WAS do not enter the finally clause.

Answer (score 1):

Does this application only exhibit this issue when running WAS?

If it's possible, I would see whether this behavior is repeatable in a different Java app server, such as JBoss or Tomcat.

When doing the testing, however, it would be crucial to use the exact same Oracle JDBC driver that WAS uses.

If not possible, I would inquire to the version of Oracle JDBC driver that WAS is using and see whether there is a newer version available.

Comment: Yes it happens only with WAS. We have other customers with JBoss and it's not happening. But WAS has it's own JVM, so who knows...

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking the issue right now be JDK related, assuming that the Oracle JDBC driver versions running on WAS vs. Jboss are the same.
The only thing I can think of is to put on tracing on WAS and send it off to IBM.  Have they been helpful in resolving the issue?